# Python: Save multiple strings with separator in one variable

Tags: python, sql, pandas, date, variables

to include a variable in my SQL statement I need a variable that stores several months.
I named it `months`
I don't copy the whole SQL-statement here, because it is irrelevant for the problem, but here is a snippet, where the variable should be used:

```
...
FROM database
    year = '{current_year}'
    AND month IN ({months})
...
```

An example how the variable should look like would be the following:

```
Ex 1: months = '1', '2', '3'  
Ex 2: months = '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'
```

It depends on the last month, how many numbers are saved as a string in it, so its dynamic. Because of that I cant save each month in one Variable and add it.
I had added the months as a list so far.

```
current_month = datetime.now().month
last_month = current_month -1
for x in range(last_month):
    x+=1
    monthList.append(x)
months = ", ".join( repr(e) for e in monthList )
```

The problem is, that the single numbers have the datatype string, but the quotes are missing, so that the SQL statement is executed correctly.
I'm also open for a completely different solution, I just need the correct format of the variable.

Comment: I don't really understand how you want the final statement to look. Why not just make the variable a list containing strings?

Comment: The statement should execute automatically each month. In months, the months preceding the current month should always be queried. Thus it can be that up to 12 numbers/months can occur. And I don't want to create 12 extra variables for this.

Comment: so... `", ".join(str(i) for i in range(last_month))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
current_month = 5
months = ", ".join(f"'{m}'" for m in range(current_month)) 
print(months) # '0', '1', '2', '3', '4'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **str()** and then **[slices](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-slicing-in-python/)** the string(first and last) to get the desired result by removing the [] from the list.

```
def modify_list(input):
    string_without_brackets = str(input)[1:-1]
    return string_without_brackets


item_list = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr','may']
final_result = modify_list(item_list)
print(final_result)

//Output
'jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr','may'
```

Comment: That's a very messy way of converting a list to string.